# What component does this symbol represent?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, phototransistor, midi

Can anybody please tell me the name of the component represented by this symbol (encircled in picture.)

[image: It is attached with the LED of phototransistor]

Comment: The TLP785 [is a bad choice for MIDI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195787/use-a-pc123-optocoupler-for-midi-input).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

The round symbol that contains several smaller circles is likely to be a DIN connector. There are several versions: -

[image]

And, it looks like yours is the SV50. Is the circuit from a midi controller? Here's one that looks very similar in that the same pins appear to be used: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That was really helpfull.

Comment: @ZeeshanDhillon - Welcome to the site :-) Please remember to accept the answer which best helped you solve a problem (see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information). As a new user who is asking a few questions, I recommend that you also read the [tour] and [help] to learn more about Stack Exchange sites. Again, welcome.

Comment: Sure. I'll do that. Thanks.